# Why I can't concatenate to rebuild and digits arrays the content of c char from text file?

Tags: arrays, c, string, file, digits

the program fails. I want to rebuild the content of a text file eg: `a1b2c3` to be like - `a1b2c3123`, the digits at the end of file

```
    int counterc=0;
    int counterd=0;
    char rebuild[100];
    char digits[100];
    char c;
    int i;
    FILE *fp;

    fp=fopen("1.txt","r");
    if(fp==NULL)
    {
        printf("\nERROR: File not found for opening\n");
    }
    else
    {
        while(c=fgetc(fp))
        {
            if(c==EOF)
            {
                break;
            }
            if(isdigit(c))
            {
                counterd++;
                strcat(digits,c);
            }
            else
            {
                counterc++;


                strcat(rebuild,c);
            }
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    printf("\nNumber of digits: %d ",counterd);
    printf("\nNumber of characters: %d",counterc);

    printf("\nThe content of digits[]: ");

    for( i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        printf("%s ",digits[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

if I don't use `strcat(rebuild,c)` it will printf me the number of characters
if I don't use `strcat(digits,c)` it will printf me the number of digits
why I can't put together in the digits array the characters that are digits?

Comment: `strcat()` is for concatenating two strings, not for adding single character. Both arguments of `strcat()` are required to be pointers.

Comment: `printf("%s ",digits[i]);` is also wrong. `%c` should be used to print single character.

Answer (score 1):

The strcat function expects two nul-terminated strings (arrays of char).
In your program, c is a char, not an array of chars.

Nul-terminated arrays of chars are arrays with the null '\0' char used as a string terminator. The array is larger than what you store inside.

"HELLO" => 'H' | 'E' | 'L' | 'L' |'O' | '\0' | garbage | garbage | etc.